# Finding difference between two rows in a table. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 30+ fields and I wanted to get the field name and the value that are different.

For example in table X we have

```
ID |  City      | State | Zip   | Segment_One | Segment_Two | ....
1  |            |  NY   | 14228 |   X71       |   5         |
2  |  JamesTown |  NY   | 14845 |   X72       |   5         |
```

The query should return the difference of both field name and the data.

```
ID | City      | Zip      | Segment_One
1  |           | 14228    |  X71
2  | JamesTown | 14845    |  X72
```

There is a query I can use to always limit the row to two rows.... so I guess I will always compare between the two rows, but how do I find the difference of field name and get the value for those fields?

Edit: This is what I tried but it seems it return the State even if it is different.

```
select * from 
(select a.* from X a where ROWNUM = 1 order by last_updt_date desc ) 
minus
select * from
(select b.* from X b where ROWNUM = 2 order by last_updt_date desc );
```

results:

```
ID  |  City  |  State  | Zip   |  Segment_One |  Segment_Two |
1   |        |   NY    | 14228 |  X71         |     5        | ...
```

This returns all fields in the row but I want only the differences field and values. This does not return for row 2. If I reverse the minus then it will return nothing.

Comment: What have you already researched and why didn't it satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this with a PL/SQL block and Dynamic `CURSOR`.Note that here I am 
using ID = 1 and 2 as a variable which you should know and be passing from somewhere.

`DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` ( 12c and above ) is used to display the output from the dynamically constructed cursor. Alternatively, you could use `PRINT` command to fetch and display the o/p from `REFCURSOR`.

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  v_ref SYS_REFCURSOR;
  id1 X.ID%TYPE := 1;
  id2 X.ID%TYPE := 2;
  v_col  VARCHAR2(32);
  v_cols VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR r IN
  ( SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'X'
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' 
SELECT 
CASE                 
WHEN a.'||r.column_name|| ' = ' || 'b.'|| r.column_name ||'                               
THEN a.'||r.column_name || ' END                     
FROM                           
X  a                
CROSS JOIN X b WHERE 
a.ID = :Id1 AND b.ID = :Id2' INTO v_col USING id1,id2 ;
    v_cols := v_cols ||
    CASE
    WHEN v_col IS NULL THEN
      ','||r.column_name
    END;
  END LOOP;
  v_cols := TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM v_cols);
  OPEN v_ref FOR 'select ' || v_cols || '  FROM X WHERE ID =  '||id1||'                
UNION ALL   select ' || v_cols || '  FROM X WHERE ID =  '||id2 ;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_ref);
END;
/
```

---

```
ResultSet #1


ID                 CITY      ZIP          SEGMENT_ONE 
------------------ --------- ------------ ----------- 
1                            14228        X71         
2                  JamesTown 14845        X72         


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, thanks for the answer.

I am changing X with the 'name of the table' and ID with the 'column name in the table' but for some reasons, I still don't get the difference

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a two row input and you can label the rows 1 and 2 (e.g. via the `row_number()` analytic function), this should work:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 id, NULL city, 'NY' state, 14228 zip, 'X71' segement_one, 5 segment_two from dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 id, 'JamesTown' city, 'NY' state, 14845 zip, 'X71' segement_one, 5 segment_two from dual)
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN ID = 1 AND NVL(city, '{null}') = LEAD(NVL(city, '{null}')) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            WHEN ID = 2  AND NVL(city, '{null}') = LAG(NVL(city, '{null}')) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            ELSE city
       END city,
       CASE WHEN ID = 1 AND NVL(state, '{null}') = LEAD(NVL(state, '{null}')) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            WHEN ID = 2  AND NVL(state, '{null}') = LAG(NVL(state, '{null}')) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            ELSE state
       END state,
       CASE WHEN ID = 1 AND NVL(zip, -99999999999) = LEAD(NVL(zip, -99999999999)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            WHEN ID = 2  AND NVL(zip, -99999999999) = LAG(NVL(zip, -99999999999)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            ELSE zip
       END zip,
       CASE WHEN ID = 1 AND NVL(segement_one, '{null}') = LEAD(NVL(segement_one, '{null}')) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            WHEN ID = 2  AND NVL(segement_one, '{null}') = LAG(NVL(segement_one, '{null}')) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            ELSE segement_one
       END segement_one,
       CASE WHEN ID = 1 AND NVL(segment_two, -99999999999) = LEAD(NVL(segment_two, -99999999999)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            WHEN ID = 2  AND NVL(segment_two, -99999999999) = LAG(NVL(segment_two, -99999999999)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL
            ELSE segment_two
       END segment_two
FROM  your_table;

        ID CITY      STATE        ZIP SEGEMENT_ONE SEGMENT_TWO
---------- --------- ----- ---------- ------------ -----------
         1                      14228              
         2 JamesTown            14845
```

Note that this simply returns values in the columns that don't match, and nothing in the columns that do match; you won't be able to just select the columns that don't match.

You could, however, use case statements to either output a select statement you could run which does just have the affected columns, or you could output a string containing a list of the columns that were different, if that's what you were after; it's not clear from your post exactly what you're going to do with the results of the query you're after.

Answer (score 1):

SQL just does not work like that because there always has to be a known number of columns in the result set. What you could do is:

```
with t as
 (select '1' id, ''          city, 'NY' state, '14228' Zip, 'X71' Segment_One, 5 Segment_Two from dual
  UNION ALL
  select '2' id, 'JamesTown' city, 'NY' state, '14845' Zip, 'X72' Segment_One, 5 Segment_Two from dual
 )
select *
from
 (select decode(min(id),    max(id),    '',  'ID')    as name, min(id)    as min_value, max(id)    as max_value from t
  UNION ALL
  select decode(min(city),  max(city),  '',  'CITY')  as name, min(city)  as min_value, max(city)  as max_value from t
  UNION ALL
  select decode(min(state), max(state), '',  'STATE') as name, min(state) as min_value, max(state) as max_value from t
  UNION ALL
  select decode(min(zip),   max(zip),   '',  'ZIP')   as name, min(zip)   as min_value, max(zip)   as max_value from t
 )
where name is not null
;



NAME  MIN_VALUE MAX_VALUE
----- --------- ---------
ID    1         2
ZIP   14228     14845
```

Answer (score 1):

when I did something like this before, I used the dictionary tables to generate sql for it.  Not sure if that would work for you or not.  Something like this

```
select 'select '''||column_name||''' col_name, x1.'||column_name||', x2.'||column_name||' from X x1 join X x2 on x1.id=1 and x2.id=2 where x1.'||column_name||' != x2.'||column_name||';'
from dba_tab_columns where table_name='X';
```

If you run that, it will generate 30 sql statements, one for each column, then you could run all of them and see what you get.  You might need to add an NVL if the column is nullable

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Kaushik Nayak just saved my day!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538691/14163316

My account is new so I could not write α comment but α full answer.

The original sql union some extra rows in my case, so I had to reverse it.
Here is the sql modified a little bit from the original answer and it works beautifuly.
I left some comments in the code block to show where u have to change.

```
define tableName = 'TABLE';     -- Change to your table name
define idName = 'ID';           -- Change to your ID name if its not ID
 
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    id1 number:= 1;             -- Change to the ID of the first row you want to compare
    id2 number:= 2;             -- Change to the ID of the second row you want to compare
    v_ref SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_col  VARCHAR2(32);
    v_cols VARCHAR2(3000);
BEGIN
    FOR r IN
        ( SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '&tableName'
        )
        LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
SELECT
CASE
WHEN a.'||r.column_name|| ' != ' || 'b.'|| r.column_name ||'
THEN a.'||r.column_name || ' END
FROM
&tableName  a
CROSS JOIN &tableName b WHERE
a.&idName = :id1 AND b.&idName = :id2' INTO v_col USING id1,id2 ;
            v_cols := v_cols ||
                      CASE
                          WHEN v_col IS NOT NULL THEN
                                  ','||r.column_name
                          END;
        END LOOP;
    v_cols := TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM v_cols);
    OPEN v_ref FOR 'select ' || v_cols || '  FROM &tableName WHERE &idName =  '||id1||'
UNION ALL select ' || v_cols || '  FROM &tableName WHERE &idName =  '||id2 ;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_ref);
END;
/
```

Again, thanks Kaushik Nayak a lot for the original answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the MINUS operator
This will return all records that are different between 2 recordsets/tuples
You'd have to play around with a case statement to figure out which cols are different though.

Comment: In fairness Minus is working correctly but it just isn't what you want. You need to write something that checks each col for differences (remember that Null <> Null !!!) Just saw Boneist answer above and it does what you need...